# grab elements with containing text nokogiri xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping, nokogiri

Still learning how to use nokogiri and so far can grab by css elements.There is a page I want to scrape http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results, i want to get all the results for the barclays premier league which can be rendered via an Ajax call, however this is not possible with nokogiri i have read.

So the link i have provided has many results for all different leagues so can i grab only the ones which are titled Barclays Premier League which is contained in

```
class="competition-title"
```

so far i can grab all results like so

```
def get_results # Get me all results
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
 days = doc.css('#results-data h2').each do |h2_tag|
 date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
  matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
  matches.each do |match|
    home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
    away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
    score = match.css('.score').text.strip
 Result.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, score: score, fixture_date: date)
end
```

Any help appreciated

Edit

ok so it seems as if i can use some ruby , using select? not sure how to implement though. example below

```
.select{|th|th.text =~ /Barclays Premier League/}
```

or some more reading has said xpath can be used

```
matches = h2_tag.xpath('//th[contains(text(), "Barclays Premier League")]').css('tr.report')
```

or

```
matches = h2_tag.xpath('//b/a[contains(text(),"Barclays")]/../following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
```

have tried the xpath way but clearly wrong as nothing saving

Thanks

Comment: Nokogiri can't do Ajax, nor can it do HTTP.  It only can do strings and files. But, if you know the correct URL, you can have OpenURI make the HTTP request and retrieve the XML or HTML, and pass that to Nokogiri for further processing.

Comment: out of interest can i obtain the url for an ajax called page, it should have a set of params after it shouldn't it in the console?

Comment: You can figure out the URL using Firebug or similar when the browser requests it, then copy that into your source. You have to figure out if any of the query params are dynamic, and, if so, what they should be, but once you know those things you should be able to get at the data.

Comment: got it working by grabbing the url http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results/partial/competition-118996114?structureid=5, now i can use my original logic with some minor tweaks, though @MarkThomas answer was excellent with its explanation, many things learned :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer an approach where you drill down to precisely what you need. Looking at the source, you need the match details:

```
    <td class='match-details'>
        <p>
            <span class='team-home teams'><a href='...'>Brechin</a></span>
            <span class='score'><abbr title='Score'> 0-2 </abbr></span>
            <span class='team-away teams'><a href='...'>Alloa</a></span>
        </p>
    </td>
```

You need the three text content items within the `p` element. You need this for only "Barclays Premier League".

Viewing the source, notice that the elements you need above happen to be in a table that contains scores *only* for that league. How convenient! The table can be identified by a `<th>` element contanining "Barclays Premier League". All you then have to do is identify that table using XPath:

```
matches = doc.xpath('//table[.//th[contains(., "Barclays Premier League")]]//td/p')
```

The `td/p` is sufficient because the match details is the only one containing a `p`, but you can add the class to the `td` if you want.

Then you grab your information exactly the way you have done it:

```
matches.each do |match|
  home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
  away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
  score = match.css('.score').text.strip
  ...
end
```

One remaining task: getting the date of each match. Looking back at the source, you can follow back up to the first containing table, and see that the first preceding `h2` node has it. You can express this in XPath:

```
date = match.at_xpath('ancestor::table[1]/preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text
```

**Putting it all together**

```
def get_results    
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
  matches = doc.xpath('//table[.//th[contains(., "Barclays Premier League")]]//td/p')
  matches.each do |match|
    home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
    away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
    score = match.css('.score').text.strip
    date = Date.parse(match.at_xpath('ancestor::table[1]/preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text).to_date
    Results.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, score: score, fixture_date: date)
  end
end
```

Comment: wow amazing explanation, that helps so much..will have to read over a few times to grasp i think... i know it sounds silly but how does it all fit together, am i replacing the date and matches variables in the same order as in my original setup?

Comment: I put it together for you. This is all just off the top of my head, as I'm not in front of a computer with Ruby on it, but I'm pretty sure it'll work :)

Comment: hi again, appreciate you cant test it but nothing is saving to the model at the moment, anything you can see that maybe sticks out as incorrect? im trying some things myself but no joy as yet, noticed it shoud be Result.create! but that hasnt helped (error in my code that part)

Comment: Good, but if you iterate through the dates first you won't need to go back up for them.

Comment: @pguardiario And that's what most people do, and it ends up with more code and more looping. That's why I prefer the "drill down" approach which minimizes the need for nested loops. In my opinion, if you are looking for 20 things, there should be 20 iterations. This means that occasionally you have to go back up the tree to find something, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm, more code perhaps but going back up with that xpath in a loop is an eyesore and a performance hit. It seems like a bad trade-off.

Comment: @MarkThomas I cant seem to get your code to work which is a shame, if you have a chance could you perhaps have a look, would love to accept your answer..thanks

Comment: @pguardiario How is it a performance hit when the DOM is already built? I wouldn't think it would be any worse than other XPath constructs like `//foo`.

Comment: Because you are parsing that date inside a loop instead of outside of the loop.

Comment: @Richlewis I had a bug in my XPath, fixed.

Comment: @pguardiario Ah, yes, it parses the same date multiple times. I  agree that in this case the value of this approach is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's how I would transform @Mark Thomas's solution:

```
def get_results    
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
  doc.search('h2.table-header').each do |h2|
    date = Date.parse(h2.text).to_date
    next unless h2.at('+ table th[2]').text['Barclays Premier League']
    h2.search('+ table tbody tr').each do |tr|
      home_team = tr.at('.team-home').text.strip
      away_team = tr.at('.team-away').text.strip
      score = tr.at('.score').text.strip
      Results.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, score: score, fixture_date: date)
    end
  end
end
```

By iterating over those h2's first you get:

Pros:

- pulling the date outside of a loop
- much simpler expressions (you might not be too worried about those
  but think about the guy who comes along after you.)

Cons:

- a few extra bytes of code

Comment: Nice and clean. Note that this solution parses all dates, whether or not there were any league games on that date. Also, you're doing the text matching in Ruby-land instead of Nokogiri which will be slightly slower, but allows you to use CSS exclusively which is nice.